# Re-compile VBA to run on Excel 2007 or later

Tags: excel, vba

While running the macro file getting error message (screenshot attach), In organization GPO blocked on saving the few file.

Macro used for to send emails to multiple users at once, it is trying to save the file type to "**web pages and Excel 2003 XML spreadsheets**" format which is blocked on GPO, I need help if below VBA code can be re-compile to work on Excel 2007 & later formats.

```
Sub SendMail()
Dim fieldlist(1 To 50) As Variant
SubHead = Range("SubHead").Value
cfile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Range("PendingList").Select
Sheets("Fields").Select
Range("FieldList").Select
ctr = 1
HdrStr = ""
Do While ActiveCell.Value \<\> Empty
Range("A1").Formula = "=TYPE(" & ActiveCell.Address & ")"
If Range("A1").Value = 1 Then
Else
fieldlist(ctr) = ActiveCell.Value
End If

SkipLoop1:
ctr = ctr + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop
    Sheets("Main").Select
    lcol = Range("B5").End(xlToRight).Column
    
    Do While Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Value <> Empty
        yesno = LCase(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value)
        flname = ActiveCell.Value
        If ActiveCell.Value <> Empty Then
            linemanager = ActiveCell.Value
            linemanagermailid = ActiveCell.Value
        End If
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> Empty Then
            ccmailid = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
        
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> Empty Then
            mailid = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            nameaddr = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
        
        If yesno <> "yes" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            GoTo SkipLoop
        End If
               
        dayspend = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value
        If dayspend < 10 Then
            dayspend = "  " & dayspend
        Else
        End If
        pendcnt = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value

'        If pendcnt \< 10 Then
'            pendcnt = "  " & pendcnt
'        End If
datastr = ""

Sheets("Template").Select
Cells.ClearFormats
Cells.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select
CurRow = 2
Sheets("Main").Select

        ColNo = 1
        For n = 1 To ctr - 1
            If Left(fieldlist(n), 1) = " " Then

'                Sheets("Template").Cells(CurRow, ColNo).Value = fieldlist(n, 1)
'                datastr = datastr & fieldlist(n, 1)
Else
tstr = ""

                For m = 2 To lcol
                    If Cells(5, m).Value = fieldlist(n) Then
                        tstr = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, m).Value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next m
                Sheets("Template").Cells(CurRow, ColNo).Value = tstr
                ColNo = ColNo + 1
            End If
        Next n
        lrow = Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row
    
    CurRow = CurRow + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        
        Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Empty And ActiveCell.Row <= lrow
            dayspend = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value
            If dayspend < 10 Then
                dayspend = "  " & dayspend
            Else
            End If
            pendcnt = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value
        
        ColNo = 1
        For n = 1 To ctr - 1
            If Left(fieldlist(n), 1) = " " Then
            Else
                tstr = ""
                fnd = False
                For m = 1 To lcol
                    If Cells(5, m).Value = fieldlist(n) Then
                        tstr = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, m).Value
                        fnd = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next m
                Sheets("Template").Cells(CurRow, ColNo).Value = tstr
                ColNo = ColNo + 1
            End If
        Next n
        CurRow = CurRow + 1

'            datastr = datastr & Chr(10) & "              " & Format(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "            " & dayspend & "                  " & pendcnt
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Loop

Sheets("Template").Select
Range("A1", Range("A1").Offset(0, ctr - 2).Address).Select
Selection.Value = fieldlist
Selection.Font.Bold = True

        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'        Range("F1").ColumnWidth = 12

        lrow1 = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        lcol1 = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        Range("A1", Cells(1, lcol1).Address).Select
        setborders
        Range("A2", Cells(lrow1, lcol1).Address).Select
        setborders
        Range("A1").Select
        Range("A1", Cells(lrow1, lcol).Address).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    
        mailid1 = linemanagermailid
        
        mesg = "Dear PO Initiator," & "<br><br>"
        mesg = mesg & Range("Mesg").Value & "<br>"

'        mesg = mesg & datastr & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

        mesg1 = "<br>" & "Regards" & "<br><br>"
        
        mesg1 = mesg1 & Range("Signature").Value
            
            Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set olMail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            
            With olMail
                .To = mailid
                .CC = ccmailid & ";" & mailid1
                .Subject = SubHead
                .HTMLBody = mesg & RangetoHTML(Range("A1", Cells(lrow1 + 1, lcol1).Address)) & mesg1

'                .Display
.Send
End With
Sheets("Main").Select

'            tt.Subject = SubHead
'            tt.Body = mesg
'            tt.Recipients.Add mailid
'            tt.CC = ccmailid & ";" & mailid1

'            tt.Send
SkipLoop:

    Loop

End Sub
Sub GetFiles()
folder = Range("Folder").Value
If Right(folder, 1) \<\> "" Then
folder = folder & ""
End If
ff = Dir(folder & "*.*")
Range("FileList").Select
Range(ActiveCell.Address, ActiveCell.Offset(200#).Address).ClearContents
Range("FileList").Select
Do While ff \<\> ""
ActiveCell.Value = ff
ff = Dir
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
.Cells(1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
On Error Resume Next
.DrawingObjects.Visible = True
.DrawingObjects.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
End With

lrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
lcol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( \_
SourceType:=xlSourceRange, \_
Filename:=TempFile, \_
Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, \_
Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1", Cells(lrow, lcol).Address).Address, \_
HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)

 .Publish (True) //here getting compilation error

End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", \_
"align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso  = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What is the exact compilation error you're getting?  It seems unlikely that your GPO is affecting compilation.